# Firestore quota exceeded for a flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have recently started experiencing this error on a flutter app while testing on a physical device. The project is on blaze plan.

*[WatchStream]: (23d22c) Stream closed with status: Status{code=RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, description=Quota exceeded., cause=null}*

While I am getting this response on the flutter app. I am not experiencing it on an angular app that is querying the same collection on the same project.

Here is the code that is calling firestore on the app.

```
@override
  Stream<Either<TripFailure, KtList<Trip>>> watchAll(
      {required String departureTown,
      required String destinationTown,
      required int passengerCount,
      required DateTime travelDate}) async* {

    yield* _firestore

        .collection('trips')
        // .where("available_seats", isEqualTo: 60)
        // .where('trip_date', isEqualTo: travelDate)
        // .where('route_search_param', arrayContains: {
        //   "departure_town": "$departureTown",
        //   "destination_town": "$destinationTown"
        // })
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => right<TripFailure, KtList<Trip>>(
              snapshot.docs
                  .map((e) => TripDTO.fromFirestore(e).toDomain())
                  .toImmutableList()
                  .filter((e) => e.availableSeats! >= passengerCount),
            ))
        .onErrorReturnWith((e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
          ///post error to firebasecrashlytics
          FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(e, StackTrace.current);
          if (e is FirebaseException &&
              e.message!.contains('PERMISSION_DENIED')) {
            return left(const TripFailure.insufficientPermission());
          } else {
            log(e.toString());
            return left(const TripFailure.unexpected());
          }
        });
  }
```

Here is the code snippet that is triggering the call.

```
class TripsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<BookingFormBloc, BookingFormState>(
      buildWhen: (p, c) => p != c,
      builder: (BuildContext context, state) {
        if (state.dateField!.isValid() &&
            state.departureTownField!.isValid() &&
            state.destinationTownField!.isValid() &&
            state.passengersField!.isValid()) {

        
          BlocProvider.of<TripWatcherBloc>(context).add(
              TripWatcherEvent.watchAllStarted(
                  travelDate: state.dateField!.getOrCrash(),
                  departureTown: state.departureTownField!.getOrCrash(),
                  destinationTown: state.destinationTownField!.getOrCrash(),
                  passengerCount: state.passengersField!.getOrCrash()));
        }

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text(
              'Select a bus',
            ),
          ),
          body: TripsStatesHolder(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried running same web app in any different browser? It may be the case of cache in web app due to which it's showing on even exceeding quota.

Another thing. You can visit the usage tab from firestore to see the daily usage.

Comment: I have tried in two other browsers, the web app is reading the firestore collection just fine. Please note that I am trying now after midnight, my current read statistics are at around 196 for the day and still the flutter app is getting exceeded result.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a limit to the query resolved my issue(even though my result set was very small, just 3 documents). Try it if you don't have it implemented in your query.

```
Firestore.instance
            .collection('collection')
            .where("item", isEqualTo: someValue)
            .limit(10)
            .snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing your  case, I found that the issue you're seeing is the “exhausted quotas” error, which means you'll need to increase your quota.
I propose you to review this documentation for more information about [price](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) and consider upgrading to the Blaze plan (which has a pay as you go basis).

One probable reason for this is that you may be over a [Firestore limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits) that occurs regardless of plan. In a variety of conditions, the system may return "resource exhausted."
To get a more realistic picture of how much your database is being used, I recommend going to the [Google Cloud Platform](http://cloud.google.com/) console. This is something I recommend because the Firebase Console isn't always as accurate as the GCP one.

According to the error message: `[code=resource-exhausted]` can be due to over passing the cache of the device/emulator.

Using Firestore settings, you can follow the next options to avoid that issue:

- Setting a higher cache limit
- Constantly deleting the cache

Comment: Hi Jose, the project is on blaze plan. The collection I was querying was very small. So it was strange that I was getting this response. I reached out to firebase support but they referred me to flutter support instead but I did not reach out to flutter. I ended up paginating my results even though I was already expecting about three documents only.